# mongoosejs: error in executing user.save() method to save data to mongodb

Tags: mongoose

When the dbUser is instantiated and given value in the same instance the function dbUser.save can be called to input data into localhost: mongodb.

```
var gmailUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
displayName: String,
emails: [ { value: String } ],
name: { familyName: String, givenName: String } 
})

// compiling our schema into a Model.
var gmailUser = mongoose.model('gmailUser', gmailUserSchema);
var dbUser = new gmailUser ({
                displayName: 'profile.displayName',
                emails: [{value: 'profile.emails'}] ,
                name: { familyName: 'profile.familyName',
                givenName: 'profile.givenName' }
            });

dbUser.save(function (err) {
  if (err) // ...
  console.log('could not save');
});
```

But if i put the value into 'dbUser' seperate from the constructor function.

```
// defining schema 
var gmailUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
displayName: String,
emails: [ { value: String } ],
name: { familyName: String, givenName: String } 
})

// compiling our schema into a Model.
var gmailUser = mongoose.model('gmailUser', gmailUserSchema);
var dbUser = new gmailUser;

dbUser = {
                displayName: '1profile.displayName',
                emails: [{value: '1profile.emails'}] ,
                name: { familyName: '1profile.familyName',
                givenName: '1profile.givenName' }
}


dbUser.save(function (err) {
 if (err) // ...
 console.log('could not save');
});
```

I get the following error upon compilation:

```
dbUser.save(function (err) {
       ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Documents/herokuApp/onlymongoose-3.js:65:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing your original dbUser object when you do this:

```
var dbUser = new gmailUser;

dbUser = {
                displayName: '1profile.displayName',
                emails: [{value: '1profile.emails'}] ,
                name: { familyName: '1profile.familyName',
                givenName: '1profile.givenName' }
}
```

You can update the fields individually by doing something like:

```
dbUser.displayName = '1profile.displayName';
dbUser.emails = [{value: '1profile.emails'}];
dbUser.name = { familyName: '1profile.familyName' };
dbUser.givenName = '1profile.givenName';
```